# Why won't my script run in Microsoft Edge (IE)?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

I have the following script, which I've been editing using Chrome. I just realized, however, that it does not work in the IE browser. I've read previous posts on here and it seems as though it has to do with adding in `return false;` within the functions. I've tried that but it doesn't seem to help.

Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/variablegeneration.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
    $this = $(this)
    var split = $this.html().split("|")
    if( split.length == 2 ){
        $this.html('<span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span><span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>')
 //////////I'VE TRIED ADDING VARIOUS ITERATIONS OF CODE HERE
    }    
});
});

</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
function randomBetween (min, max) {
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
//////////I'VE TRIED ADDING VARIOUS ITERATIONS OF CODE HERE
}

function randomBetweenAndExcluding (min, max, array) {
  var random;
  do {
    random = randomBetween(min, max);
  } while(array.includes(random));
  return random;
//////////I'VE TRIED ADDING VARIOUS ITERATIONS OF CODE HERE
}

array = [1,2,5];
var random1High = randomBetween(2, 10);
 $('.random1High').html(random1High );

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    TEST  <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No1"></span> Less than 1:  <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6lessthanNo1"></span> Others:   <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No2"></span> / <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No3"></span>  / <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No4"></span> / <span class = "GenerateRandomNumber2to6No5"></span> 
</body>
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes()` has poor support in IE/Edge.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is not IE. Please make yourself clear which browser you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's Microsoft Edge. I don't have IE, so I can't say with certainty if it doesn't work in IE as well. How can I resolve the array.prototype.includes() issue?